# DirectX error when loading GTA4

Tags: grand-theft-auto-iv, directx-9, directx

I'm getting the following error when trying to load Grand Theft Auto 4.

> **DD3D50**
>   D3D Error - DirectX 9 video card required

My PC specs:

- Core 2 Duo Intel
- 4 GB RAM
- 500 Hard drive
- But **NO GRAPHICS CARD**

My question is where can I get DirectX 9?
Is this DirectX 9 Software or Graphics card?

Comment: Are you certain that you don't have a switchable graphics card installed? It may read Intel HD Graphics but also check your device manager to verify that the only graphics driver is the motherboard's on-board display.

Answer (score 3):

You pc seems to have some kind of graphics card as you can read the error message ;) Your integrated graphics card may or may not support DirectX 9.

DirectX is a graphics API developed by Microsoft. Try getting the latest version of DirecX found at [Mirosoft Website](http://www.microsoft.com/de-de/download/details.aspx?id=35). You can also use Windows Device Manager to get additional information on what kind of graphics chip is in your PC and what Direct X Version it supports. Use the information to make sure you are running the latest drivers for this chip. Preinstalled drivers are often outdated.